# How to trigger a page change event in react js through browserhistory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, navigation, react-router

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
```

I am using browserHistory from react-router, I am looking for an event which is triggered whenever the page trasition/page change occurs through browserHistory. (This includes page navigation through back and forward of the browser too). It should have to be global. May be something like :

```
onNavigationChange(){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
browserHistory.listen(event => {
  console.log('listen', event.pathname);
});

<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
```

You need to use `browserHistory` object that you pass to ReactRouter.